# How to reset sort for datagridview (DataTable or DataView)

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();

 //DataView dv = table.DefaultView;
 //dgvSurveyViewer.DataSource = dv;
 dgvSurveyViewer.DataSource = table;
```

How to reset the sort after messing around the sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your data:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
...
```

Set the DataSource of grid to DefaultView of table instead of the table itself. Now you can set the sort field:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = "name";
dgvSurveyViewer.DataSource = table.Defaultview;
....
```

Once you're finished with sorting, set the sort field to string.Empty:

```
table.DefaultView.Sort = string.Empty;
```

Grid will sense the change and will repaint the control.